# In diskpart, what is the difference between deleting all a drive's partitions and cleaning it?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, diskpart

CMD's `diskpart` utility seems to have two ways to delete partitions on a USB flash drive:

1. Using `select disk #`, then `select partition #`, and `delete partition` to delete partitions individually.
2. Using `select disk #` and then `clean`.

As far as I've been able to tell, both of these methods perform the same function, requiring the resulting flash drive to be reformatted in the same way after.

**Is there any practical difference between the two methods, or do they accomplish the exact same thing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

1. `delete partition` - Needs to be issued multiple times for each partition on the disk, but lets you erase only a single partition.
2. `clean` - Needs to be issued only once to erase multiple partitions. But, is not selective about what it erases.

One is definitely more practical over the other depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, that's pretty obvious, lol. I was asking about the difference in the results between the two, but I suppose you're saying that there is none.